# Complex system solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis

I need to solve the following complex system

> $(4 − 2i)x − 4y = 0$
>
> $5x − (4 + 2i)y = 0$
>
> $−16x + y − (7 + 2i)z = 0$

My professor claims that the solution is $(4 − 2i, 5, −9 − 2i)$. I do not think that this solution works. Anywats it seems not easy to solve by hand.Am I right??

Comment: Have you tried plugging in the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y=\frac14(4-2i)x$$
solves both of the first 2 equations
the third becomes ...

$$-16x+\frac14(4-2i)x = (7+2i)z 
\\ (-64 + 4-2i)x=(28+8i)z$$
so
$$ z=x\frac{-60-2i}{28+8i} 
\\ \frac zx = -\frac 12 \frac{30+i}{7+2i}
\\ \frac zx = -\frac 1{106} (30+i)(7-2i)
 \\ \frac zx = -\frac 1{106}(212-53i)
 \\ \frac zx = -\frac 1{2}(4-i)
$$
So the solution is 
$$ (x,y,z)=k(4,4-2i, -8+2i)      $$
Where $k$ is any complex number
in particular , for $k=\frac{4+2i}{4}$
$$(x,y,z) = (4+2i, 5, -9-2i)$$

Which is what your prof said except $(4+2i)$ instead of $(4-2i)$

Comment: Thank you. Very clear